# ElasticSearch Query to find intersection of two queries

Tags: elasticsearch

Records exist in this format: `{user_id, state}`.

I need to write an elasticsearch query to find all user_id's that have both states present in the records list.

For example, if sample records stored are:

```
{1,a}
{1,b}
{2,a}
{2,b}
{1,a}
{3,b}
{3,b}
```

The output from running the query for this example would be

```
{"1", "2"}
```

I've tried this so far:

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "state": [
            "a",
            "b"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "user_id_intersection": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id",
        "min_doc_count": 2, 
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but this will return

```
{"1", "2", "3"}
```

Comment: is the list of both states are defined before? if yes, you could query as AND for state A and state B and then count the facet on user_id with unique modifier

Comment: @mirzak I've edited the question to show what I've tried so far.

Comment: @Mysterion list of states is defined

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the cardinality of the states set, here 2, you can use the 
[Bucket Selector Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html)

```html
GET test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "user_ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "states_card": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "state"
          }
        },
        "state_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "states_card": "states_card"
            },
            "script": "params.states_card == 2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```